# Android O access to App settings activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

Using Android 8+ Oreo GO I can directly access my App settings from within the App itself by making a call from a menu item like this;

```
Intent intent = new 
Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
startActivity(intent);
```

This is very handy and the Settings activity looks like this;

[image]

However, it would be really nice and tidy to have the back arrow and activity text that shows when using the actual system setting activity like this;

[image]

I'm wondering if that's at all possible..?

Doesn't look like it in developer documentation viz.

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#CreateChannelGroup

UPDATE OCTOBER 15, 2018
Looks like this is simply a hazard of varying Android versions. I have two devices, both with Android verion 8.1.0 now the Samsung SM-G390Y upgraded itself from v7 this morning and looks like the lower pic with the return arrow. The other device just has the "Settings".

Does that answer my question..?

Comment: There is no requirement for it to look like either of those screenshots. The Settings app is customized by most device manufacturers.

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned that the Android is "Oreo GO"  version so it isn't loaded up with manufacturers' bloatware :o)

Comment: Yes, but there are ~24,000 Android device models, only few of which are Go. What these screens will look like will vary by model.

Comment: Sure, I get that. I'm only looking to get the little return arrow and maybe the description showing on whatever activity is opened up by the Intent to get Settings from the Oreo device. Maybe it isn't possible.